# How to make AVI files web optimized with mencoder

Tags: video, avi, performance, mencoder, conversion

In Handbrake there is an option to optimize video files for the web so that they play better online. Does mencoder have an option like that? I'm wondering if I should convert a file using handbrake after using mencoder to add subtitles, but am worried about further loss of video quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a mov container instead of an avi as you can stream that without any magic and play without downloading the whole thing.  AVI is funny about needing the last bit first...

`ffmpeg -i your.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mov`

Comment: i go back and forth between ffmpeg and mencoder for different bits of functionality

Comment: I want to upload to youtube. Would mp4 be a better format? I noticed that when I download videos from youtube they are in mp4 format. Or maybe it doesn't matter because youtube re-encodes the video anyway?

Comment: they re-encode anyway....check their faq, they have preferred encodings...same with vimeo, they have preferred encodings as well.

Comment: So when they re-encode, does that automatically make it web optimized? Or is it still better to web optimize the video before uploading it to them?

Comment: i would look at their faq to see recommended encoding options...web optimized usually just means lower resolution or frame rate, but with streaming in HD now, not so much